# Deploy Web Application onto Weblogic 12c Server

Tags: java, oracle, maven, pom.xml, weblogic12c

I am quite new with weblogic servers and web applications in general. I currently have been given a web application and told to run it on my pc by deploying it on a weblogic server I have installed and setup....Moreover I am using maven on Netbeans 8.2.

So I have been trying to run my web application which is now connected on my weblogic server but been getting the following deployment failed message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jrf.PortabilityLayerException.

At first I thought that I was missing oracle.jrf from my MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules but seems I have that folder.

My question is, the deployment failed I am getting means that there is something missing from the oracle.jrf folder, if yes what files should I have in that folder then, or is it something else that is causing the deployment to fail..

Again sorry if this question is not making much sense I am new to this...Let me know how I could make it more clear...

*The following is the message I am getting after I run my web application:*

### BUILD SUCCESS

Total time: 3.971 s
Finished at: 2021-07-16T11:55:29+03:00
Final Memory: 17M/310M

Deploying on Oracle WebLogic Server

> profile mode: false

> debug mode: false

> force redeploy: true

Distributing C:\project_name\target\project_name.war

Deploying C:\project_name\target\project_name.war

**Deployment failed. The message was: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jrf.PortabilityLayerException**

Comment: How do you deploy your web app ?
The error message is from the weblogic server log or from your deploy tool ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Ehm There are two ways I am trying to deploy it: 
1) I just try to run the web app (maven project) from Netbeans, and its trying to deploy it on the Weblogic itself before running. 
2) The other way I try to deploy the .war file through the Weblogic server Administration console 12c > Deployments > install > .war file . 
Is that what your asking?

Comment: Yes. 
Did it work with the admin console ?

Comment: Nope getting this error as well Deployment failed. The message was: 
1-> Error An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
2-> Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jrf.PortabilityLayerException
3-> Error oracle.jrf.PortabilityLayerException

Comment: Your application seems not to be a simple web app but may require additional frameworks from Oracle. Is it an SOA, OSB, OBI, etc... application ?

Comment: Its a SOA...But you are right seems I am missing a bunch of libraries for some reason, in the projectname/target/projectname/WEB-INF/lib/. I have copied the jrf-api.jar file from my oracle_home/oracle_common/modules/oracle.jrf directory and prompted me to a new error of another library :/. I will try do the same now. I am unsure as to why the project is missing so many libraries tbh

Comment: Before updating your application you should check  
1. You have installed Oracle SOA Suite and not only WebLogic Server
2. Your domain is a SOA domain and not a "simple" weblogic server domain

Comment: So now that I have already installed and setup weblogic 12c, can I just install SOA on it. Or do I have to uninstall weblogic and then install SOA?

Comment: Both solutions are possible but Oracle provides an installer that can install WebLogic and SOA in a single time. 
Don't forget SOA requires a database to work with.

Comment: Thanks that helps...Although I have weblogic 12.2.1.3 but cannot find nowhere SOA 12.2.1.3 only 12.2.1.4 which is a pain....

Comment: Go to [https://edelivery.oracle.com](https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/SoftwareDelivery) and search for "Oracle SOA Suite"